# $request->input returns null laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a form with 3 fields - start date, end date and pattern. I want to pick the values from the input and check if those are empty. if not then compare the dates and perform action. By when I tried passing the value `$request->input('from')` in $status, it returned null.

my form:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form action="App\Http\Controllers\HolidayController@addSchedule" method="POST" autocomplete="off" id="scheduleForm">
           @include('partials.holidayFormModal')
    </form>
 </div>
```

holidayFormModal:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('assets/custom/css/schedule/scheduleForm.css') }}">

<div class="form-group row col-md-12 date-picker">
    <label class="col-sm-2 date-picker-label" for="from">
        {{ __('messages.schedule_period') }}
    </label>
    <div class="input-group col-sm-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="start_datepicker" type="text" name="from" autocomplete="off" readonly>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    <div class="input-group col-sm-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="end_datepicker" type="text" name="to" autocomplete="off" readonly>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row col-md-12 motif-picker">
    <label class="col-sm-2 motif-label" for="meotif">
        {{ __('messages.schedule_motif') }}
    </label>
    <input class="form-control col-sm-10" type="text" id="motif" name="motif" max="60">
</div>
<div class="col-md-11"></div>
<div class="col-md-1" id="schedule-submit">
    <button class="btn" type="button" id="schedule_form_submit_button">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle fa-3x"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

web.php :

```
Route::get('/holidays', ['uses' => $controllerNamespace . 'HolidayController@index', 'as' => 'holidays']);
Route::post('/holidayAdd',['uses' => $controllerNamespace . 'HolidayController@addSchedule', 'as' => 'holidayAdd']);
```

HolidayController:

```
public function addSchedule(Request $request) {
    $scheduleModelObj = new ScheduleModel;
    $scheduleModelObj->from = $request->from;
    $scheduleModelObj->to = $request->to;
    $scheduleModelObj->motif = $request->motif;
    
    $fromDate = str_replace('/', '-', $request->from);
    $toDate = str_replace('/', '-', $request->to);

    $f = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fromDate));
    $t = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($toDate));

    if ($f == '' || $t == '' || $scheduleModelObj->motif == '') {
        $returnMessage['date'] = __('messages.schedule_end_date_error');
        $returnMessage['motif'] = __('messages.schedule_motif_error');
        $status = 'error';
    } else {
        if ($f < $t) {
            $scheduleModelObj->searchSchedule($scheduleModelObj->from, $scheduleModelObj->to);
            $status = 'success';
        }
        $returnMessage['date'] = __('messages.schedule_end_date_error');
        $returnMessage['motif'] = __('messages.schedule_motif_error');
        $status = 'error';
    }
    return ['status' => $status, 'message' => $returnMessage];
}
```

Comment: "*when I tried passing the value `$request->input('from')` in $status, it returned null*" - I don't see any code which does this?  Have you tried some debugging, eg `dd($request)` in your `addSchedule()` method will show you exactly what was received. Check your browser devtools, click the network tab, and click on the POST, are the fields being sent as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <form action="{{route('holidayAdd')}}" method="POST" autocomplete="off" id="scheduleForm">
           @include('partials.holidayFormModal')
    </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why should OP "_try this_"? What did you change? What was the problem?

Comment: You should add your route name within the action attribute.

Comment: I tried this, but it still gives me null. the input values are not being picked up and I don't know why.

Comment: debug your form in client side to check if the problem is in backend or client side.

Comment: If you answer a question, always explain what you've changed, and why it solves the problem. Copy/pasting your answer will in some cases solve the problem, but the OP (and other people with the same problem) will learn nothing from it.

Comment: Sorry for my time!